Help needed in recreating ANOVA test results from study
I am aiming to recreate ANOVA tests as part of Study 1 from the following research paper related to some psychological factors:

https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2021.738447

There are altogether 80 participants in the study, 40 of them belong to Group A (high victim sensitivity) and the other half to Group B (low victim sensitivity).
I want to replicate the 2 (victim sensitivity: low vs. high) × 2 (group membership: ingroup vs. outgroup) ANOVA on the inclusion-of-other-in-self scale scores. The results are F(1, 78) = 369.85, p < 0.001, partial η2 = 0.83.
There is also a 2 (victim sensitivity: low vs. high) × 2 (group membership: ingroup vs. outgroup) ANOVA on the allocation expectation with a significant main effect of the group membership F(1, 78) = 75.48, p < 0.001, partial η2 = 0.49, as well as a 3-way ANOVA with 2 (victim sensitivity: low vs. high) × 2 (group membership: ingroup vs. outgroup) × 2 (proposal size: offer 8:2 vs. 6:4), with a a significant main effect of group membership again F(1, 78) = 21.10, p < 0.001, partial η2 = 0.21.
I have trouble replicating these results with the given dataset, with the following variables:

Number = ID
VS_group = victim sensitivity
gender = gender
age = age
VS = victim sensitivity score
PT = perspective-taking score
HH = honesty-humility score
in_dis = distance to the ingroup member
in_ep = ingroup allocation expectation
in_82 = ingroup 8:2 offer
in_64 = ingroup 6:4 offer
out_dis = distance to the outgroup member
out_ep = outgroup allocation expectation
out_82 = outgroup 8:2 offer
out_64 = outgroup 6:4 offer
IGS_2 = in_82 - out_82
IGS_4 = in_64 - out_64

Sneak peek into the data:

My issue is, that I am not sure how to group and recode the data into the categories required by the ANOVA test. High and low victim sensitivity are given, however, ingroup and outgroup membership is from the perspective of the offer proposal. I tried to recode the data so each subject is present twice: first with ingroup proposal data (in_82, in_64, in_ep) and in another row with outgroup proposal data (out_82, out_64, in_ep). However, when I try to run the multiple-way ANOVA, I get completely different results from the ones presented in the paper.
At this point, I am lost as to how to prepare the data to perform the required ANOVA tests. Any help to guidance would be much appreciated!

Have you contacted the authors of the article? They are most knowledgeable to answer this question.

Yes, I tried to reach out to them, but they didn't respond...

The inclusion-of-other-in-self scale scores are missing? Another interesting bit is that the text reads as if there are N = 80 data points and two binary predictors but the reported F statistic has 1 numerator and 78 denominator degrees of freedom. (These are the degrees of freedom for one-way ANOVA on a binary predictor.)

I would guess that the authors use the in_dis and out_dis variables (it's on a scale from 1 to 7) for calculating the inclusion-of-other-in-self scale scores, but this would mean two separate dependent variables. Yes, I noticed that about the F statistic, can't really figure it out.

It's a tricky situation. I admit I only skimmed the paper but I'm not sure there is enough details to reproduce the analysis fully. Not sure what a good next step is either but this might be a good question for the Academia stack exchange?
